# NameError: uninitialized constant MIME

Tags: ruby, wordpress, rubypress

This line of rubypress code:

```
:type => MIME::Types.type_for(FILENAME).first.to_s,
```

is barfing with the following error:

```
NameError: uninitialized constant MIME
```

The whole block is:

```
FILENAME='myFile.png'
wp.uploadFile(:data => {
    :name => FILENAME,
    :type => MIME::Types.type_for(FILENAME).first.to_s,
    :bits => XMLRPC::Base64.new(IO.read(FILENAME))
    })
```

Any suggestions what the problem is?

Answer (score 7):

Add `require 'mime/types'` to the top of your file.

Comment: As of 2020 this gives `LoadError: cannot load such file -- mime/types`

Comment: Make sure you have `mime-types` added to your gem deps?

Comment: I hadn't added a gem for it, no — I was just using Rails and was expecting a built-in. Maybe you should add that gem dependency to your answer if that's a necessary step. (I added an answer below that works with no extra gems)

Comment: I don't know if that's a necessary step. My answer is 5 years old. Glad you figured out something that worked for you.

Answer (score 2):

```rb
extension =  File.extname(file).split(".")[1]
Mime::Type.lookup_by_extension(extension)
```

Answer (score 0):

A little late to the party.

After a recent Ruby upgrade, I've found that `MIME::TYPES` could not be initialized. A more modern solution is to use [marcel](https://github.com/rails/marcel), which is already included as a dependency with the recent rails version.

```rb
Marcel::MimeType.for(file)
```